# Is there a measure I could apply to measure spread of predictions?

Tags: similarities

I have some data with predictors that work out the value of changes applied to an `ID`.

Each `TYPE` is a predictor for the `CHANGE` applied to an `ID`.

Below is an example of the data:

```
ID  CHANGE   TYPE    VALUE   STATE
A   RA       1       1.14    POS
A   RA       2       0.96    POS
A   RA       3       0.78    POS
A   RA       4       0.84    POS
A   RA       5       0.92    POS
B   SR       1       1       POS
B   SR       2       0.82    POS
B   SR       3       -0.012  NEG
B   SR       4       -0.036  NEG
B   SR       5       -0.02   NEG
C   GW       1       -0.86   NEG
C   GW       2       -0.77   NEG
C   GW       3       -0.82   NEG
C   GW       4       -0.62   NEG
C   GW       5       -0.74   NEG
```

Is there a measure of a distance/spread I could apply to each `ID`? For example, `C` has all predictions very close to each other so we can be confident in the prediction but `B`'s predictions are spread out so we are less confident.

[image: data example]

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps too obvious, but you could use the standard deviation of the predictions, or a confidence interval if you have enough predictions.

Comment: Apologies for the delay, thank you for answering. I was thinking about standard deviation or the mean absolute deviation :)

I wasn't sure about confidence intervals as the points aren't a sample from a population?